# Установка SASS в PhpStorm/WebStorm

Tags: phpstorm, sass, mac, webstorm

Как установить на **MacOS** (вроде я это сделал через терминал, но не уверен, что правильно) и настроить SASS в **PhpStorm/WebStorm** ?

**ОС: MacOS (High Siera сейчас стоит)**

Уверен, что так не должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уберите знаки `{`,`}`,`;`

Comment: @kizoso там оказывается надо было через командную строку установить File Watcher. А так, да, Вы правы в том, что я в SASS использую скобки и точки с запятыми. Я решил, что в SCSS намного приятнее, чем в SASS